# I use "HttpContext.Current" but debug got error "HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[.Net Core 3.1]

I need to set SessionTimeout redirect to login page. How can I use HttpContext.Current?
This is my code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace DemoMVCLogin.Class
{
  public class SessionManagement
  {

  }


  public class SessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
        HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` is no longer part of .Net Core.

Access the `HttpContext` via [`ActionContext.HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_HttpContext) property

> Gets or sets the HttpContext for the current request.

```
public class SessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        HttpContext httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```